# Tweepy bypass 403 Forbidden 187 - Status is a duplicate

Tags: python, twitter, tweepy

I am creating a bot that Tweets duplicate tweets overtime. I am receiving this error due to the tweet being duplicate:
403 Forbidden
187 - Status is a duplicate

I want to enable duplicate tweets via tweepy.  How is it possible to do so? Is there a workaround? Does Tweepy not check for duplicates after a certain amount of time has passed since the previous tweet?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

The `403` appears to come from the Twitter API.

According to [their documentation](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/twitter-api/v1/tweets/post-and-engage/api-reference/post-statuses-update), "Any attempt that would result in duplication will be blocked, resulting in a 403 error".

So it is not possible to enable duplicate tweets via `tweepy` (or other libraries, or using the Twitter API directly).

A possible workaround is modifying the tweet slightly, e.g. adding "(dup)" to duplicate tweets.

Comment: If you want to get fancy, you can also use zero-width spaces or other characters so the Tweet looks identical to a human user, but is not identical otherwise.
https://unicode-explorer.com/c/200B

Comment: @AlexHuszagh that is a great idea